# How to use iconv for utf8 conversion?

Tags: c

I want to convert data in other encodings to UTF-8. I'm stranded with following problems:

1. Executing the attached code gives me: `pointer being freed was not allocated` in iconv().
   Why does iconv play with my memory?
2. When I don't free(dst) it doesn't crash but nothing is printed. Not even gibberish.
   What's wrong?

---

```
void utf8(char **dst, char **src, const char *enc)
{
    iconv_t cd;
    size_t len_src,
           len_dst;

    len_src = strlen(*src);
    len_dst = len_src * 8; // is that enough for ASCII to UTF8?

    cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", enc);

    *dst = (char *)calloc(len_dst+1, 1);

    iconv(cd, src, &len_src, dst, &len_dst);
    iconv_close(cd);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *src = "hello world";
    char *dst;

    utf8(&dst, &src, "ASCII");
    printf("%s\n", dst);

    free(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, UTF-8 characters never take more than 6 bytes each. `len_src * 8` is an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [`iconv()` description at POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html)

```
size_t iconv(iconv_t cd, char **restrict inbuf,
       size_t *restrict inbytesleft, char **restrict outbuf,
       size_t *restrict outbytesleft);
```

> The variable pointed to by outbuf shall be updated to point to the byte following the last byte of converted output data.

You need to save and restore `*dst` (and possibly `*src`) inside your `utf8()` function.

Comment: Thx! Any idea why the function was written to modify the pointers? Doesn't look like a good practice to me.

Comment: If the conversion isn't complete you get the position (both input and output) at which conversion can continue. If the function accepted `char *` or promised not to change the arguments, you'd need to pass another argument for that kind of management. I'll leave open the question of which of the two options is "better" ...

Comment: I was trying to find this bug in my code for weeks. You saved me. Thanks!